# Получить номер месяца в квартале

Tags: sql, postgresql, redshift

Ломаю голову над задачей: хочу получить номер месяца в рамках квартала. Номер должен быть от 1 до 3.
У меня есть сгенерированая последовательность дат в которых нужно посчитать номер месяца в каждом квартале. Я придумал обходить проблему череp case
Но может кто нибудь может подсказать или направить на более оптимальное решение?
Задачу решаю в Redshift.
Фрагмент запроса:

```
SELECT date '2014-12-31' + INTERVAL AS date_s,     
           CASE 
              WHEN DATE_PART(dayofweek, date_s) = 0
              THEN 7
              ELSE DATE_PART(dayofweek, date_s) 
           END AS dwn,
           DATE_PART(day, date_s) AS dmn,
           (date_s- DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date_s)::date) + 1 AS day_of_quarter,
           EXTRACT(doy from date_s) AS day_of_yer,
           CASE 
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 4
           THEN 1
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 5
           THEN 2
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 6
           THEN 3
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 7
           THEN 1
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 8
           THEN 2
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 9
           THEN 3
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 10
           THEN 1
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 11
           THEN 2
           WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) = 12
           THEN 3
           ELSE EXTRACT(month FROM date_s)
       END AS month_quarter_number
     FROM generate_series(1, (date '2021-01-01' - date '2015-01-01')) interval;
```

Comment: остаток от деления номера месяца на 3. 0 заменить на 3

Answer (score 2):

Можно вычислить номер месяца в квартале при помощи остатка при делении на 3

```sql
(EXTRACT(month FROM date_s) - 1) % 3 + 1
```

Может понадобиться явное приведение типа:

```sql
(EXTRACT(month FROM date_s)::int - 1) % 3 + 1
```

```sql
SELECT 
    date '2014-12-31' + INTERVAL AS date_s,     
    CASE 
        WHEN DATE_PART(dayofweek, date_s) = 0 THEN 7
        ELSE DATE_PART(dayofweek, date_s) 
    END AS dwn,
    DATE_PART(day, date_s) AS dmn,
    (date_s- DATE_TRUNC('quarter', date_s)::date) + 1 AS day_of_quarter,
    EXTRACT(doy from date_s) AS day_of_yer,
    (EXTRACT(month FROM date_s)::int - 1) % 3 + 1 AS month_quarter_number
FROM 
    generate_series(1, (date '2021-01-01' - date '2015-01-01')) interval;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! :)

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, можете поставить зеленую галочку :)

Comment: Слева от ответа есть серая галочка, при [принятии ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) она станет зеленой См. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers),